# Best way to format NSDecimalNumber in scientific notation

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, scientific-notation, nsdecimalnumber

I looked around but can't find a clear answer. I have an NSDecimalNumber object I would like to display in scientific notation. The NSNumberFormatter looked appealing, but I see a loss of precision in the conversion which doesn't work for this application. I can devise a formula, but would like to avoid that if possible.

What is the best approach here?